# node/express server. parameter is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

What is going wrong with my string parameter?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var braintree = require("braintree");
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var user = require('../shared/userFunctions.js')



//register functions
app.register = function(api) {
api.get('get_client_token', generateClientToken);
api.get('find_customer', findCustomer);
api.post('checkout', checkout);
api.post('create_customer', createCustomer);
api.post('create_payment_method', newPaymentMethod);
}
```

The checkout function is where I call the local function with user.getuser

```
function checkout(request, response) {
var email = request.body.email;
var nonce = request.body.payment_method_nonce;
//var nonce = req.param("payment_method_nonce");
var amount = request.body.amount;



// Use payment method nonce here
gateway.transaction.sale({
    amount: amount,
    paymentMethodNonce: nonce,
}, function (err, result) {


    if(err){
        return response.send(500, "Checkout failed")
    }



   /* request.add({"amount": 10})
    request = nonce;
    newPaymentMethod(request);*/
   /* return res.send(200, "Checkout Success")*/
});

user.getuser(email, function(u){




    console.log("returning user: " + JSON.stringify(u))
    return response.send(200, JSON.stringify(u))


})
}
```

If I hard core the email address into the mongoose query, it returns the user. What gives? Please give advice on my node async style. I am still new to it, but sometimes error first fucntions don't work and sometimes I need "next". The static email works but is my style the problem?

```
exports.getuser = function(email, res) {


var db = mongoose.connection;

mongoose.connect(process.env.MongoConnectionString);
db.on('error', function () {


});

db.once('open', function callback() {
    console.log("Sucessfully Logged into mongo");


    User.findOne({email:email}, function (err, user, next) {
        if (err) {
            mongoose.disconnect();
            return next(err);
        }
        mongoose.disconnect();
        console.log("Sending user response");
        if(!user){

            console.log("failed to get user")
            return
        }

        return res(user);
    });

});
```

**EDIT**
This function is responsible for calling the internal function. It seems to work exactly like the checkout function, except for its magical ability to work correctly.

```
function getUser(request, response) {
var email = request.param('email');

user.getuser(email, function(user){

    return response.send(200, JSON.stringify(user))

})
};
```

Using a REST client so I assure you that body/params is not the problem. Thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: If you put a `console.log(email)` in before User.findOne is it the same as it would be when you hardcode it? Also, do you get an errors?

Comment: its printing undefined when I console.log(email). What the heck is going on? `var email = req.param` or `var email = req.body.email` and then call `getUser(email)` should work

Comment: Then your route probably isn't receiving the email off the body. I would try `console.log(req.body.email)` and `console.log(req.body)` to see if the data is what I'm expecting.

Comment: Are you sure there is an email property in your request.body?

Answer (score 0):

you can check your paratmeter in your api like this :

```
 var password = req.body.passwordBrow || '';
 var uidUser = req.body.uidUser || '';
```

and then check it :

```
if(password && uidUser){
  // here you can log your parameters
}else{
  // the parameter is undefined, so you need to check your request in the client
       res.json({
            status : "not_ok",
            result : "empty_data",
            resultType : serverConst.EmptyParams
        });

}
```

hope it helps you.

Comment: it appears that the params are my problem. I have never seen this before. If I call the function getuser("emailaddress"), it does work. I am using bodyparser and I have never had these problems.

Comment: have you tried this in your code? and one more thing, you can replace serceConst.EmptyParams with integer or string whatever you want. if the request succesfull, you can log your parameter and see the data you pass from the client.

Comment: yes, I tried your code. the params and body are empty regardless of which I use. What is going on? Isnt this language supposed to just work? I have like 20 other functions that work in different express and node patterns. While I admittedly just switched from having models to having an API that uses models, it should not be this hard.

Comment: as Programmer you need to find the problem, the computer only following your command/sintaks, so in that case my friend, you need to find the problem by your self. it can be usefull when you log in your client and api. cuz I dont know your sintaks and have no idea why is not working.